# How do I increase wireless network throughput to above 4mb?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, file-transfer, throughput

Router: Linksys WRT610N (Simultaneous Dual Band)
PC: Windows 7
MAC: Snow Leopard

Max transfer speed: 4mbytes/sec

Other tidbits:
Wireless connection strength: Good. Both signals above 85%.

I find this abysmal! My PC connects to the G network, and has a card capable of 150mbit/s throughput. Mac is on the N network with capabilities of 300mbit/s. I know these speeds are theoretical but 4mbytes is vastly below this number.

I'm hoping there are some windows settings that will be able to help improve transfer speeds. Potentially some router settings. I'm really not sure.

What steps can I take to try and increase the efficiency of file transfer, between my pc and mac over the wireless network?

Comment: Are we talking transfer between the PC and Mac, or from the PC/Mac to the internet? If it's the latter, then what is your *actual* connection speed to the internet from your router?

Comment: I'm talking about local transfer between the clients, over the local wireless network. Not internet speeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bear in mind 300mb/s is 37.5 mB/s and that bandwidth is shared. 802.11g supports up to 54mb which is 6.75mB. If your transferring between the two clients, it'll be limited by the G one. So likely you're out of luck. Get a cat5e wire and use gigabit.

Comment: How I would love them both to be on a wired network, unfortunately it's not practical at the moment. For very large transfers, I connect ethernet between the two and bypass the network entirely. The Mac is a laptop. If both were on the N network, what would the approximate speed be?

Comment: maybe about 25mB/s ?

Comment: actually that might be a bit optimistic. Most peoples real world speeds seem to be about 100mb/s, or 12mB/s... ish. Depends on things like how many channels you use, and if there's G interference.

Comment: Hmm so close enough to double the speed give or take. Don't think it's worth going out and buying an N card for my PC considering I don't transfer all that often, when I can temporarily ethernet them together. Thanks for your help.